# Snowflake - Remove duplicate rows based on conditions met

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the below table that has duplicate start and end for the same id and same file (because I accidentally loaded the files twice from s3). So there should be only 1 filename for each id / start / end

when I run this query in my table:

```
SELECT filename, id, start, end from table where id = '262627';
```

I see the below:

| filename | id | start | end | click_total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| name_2022/01/01.csv | 262627 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-02 | 142 |
| name_2022/01/01.csv | 262627 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-02 | 142 |
| name_2022/01/02.csv | 262627 | 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-03 | 753 |
| name_2022/01/02.csv | 262627 | 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-03 | 753 |

but it should look like this:

| filename | id | start | end | click_total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| name_2022/01/01.csv | 262627 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-02 | 142 |
| name_2022/01/02.csv | 262627 | 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-03 | 753 |

Is there a query I can run to remove the duplicate rows, without hardcoding each id in the statement?

Comment: Are those 4 columns the only fields you have in the table?

Comment: @PhilCoulson No I have 1 other fields as well CLICK_TOTAL, I'll add that to my example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well given you have noted in a comment that there is actually "another column row number" you now use that to delete the high row numbers.

first a table of fake data to "work" on:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE too_much_data AS 
select *
from values
    ('name_2022/01/01.csv' ,262627, '2022-01-01','2022-01-02', 1),
    ('name_2022/01/01.csv' ,262627, '2022-01-01','2022-01-02', 2),
    ('name_2022/01/02.csv' ,262627, '2022-01-02','2022-01-03', 3),
    ('name_2022/01/02.csv' ,262627, '2022-01-02','2022-01-03', 4)
    t(filename, id, start1, end1, file_row_number);
```

now let look at that table:

```
SELECT * FROM too_much_data;
```

| FILENAME | ID | START1 | END1 | FILE_ROW_NUMBER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| name_2022/01/01.csv | 262627 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-02 | 1 |
| name_2022/01/01.csv | 262627 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-02 | 2 |
| name_2022/01/02.csv | 262627 | 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-03 | 3 |
| name_2022/01/02.csv | 262627 | 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-03 | 4 |

so these are the rows we want to delete are:

```
SELECT filename, id, start1, end1, file_row_number 
FROM too_much_data 
QUALIFY file_row_number <> min(file_row_number) over(partition by filename, id, start1, end1);
```

| FILENAME | ID | START1 | END1 | FILE_ROW_NUMBER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| name_2022/01/01.csv | 262627 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-02 | 2 |
| name_2022/01/02.csv | 262627 | 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-03 | 4 |

thus there DELETE can be:

```
DELETE FROM too_much_data as d
USING (
    SELECT filename, id, start1, end1, file_row_number 
    FROM too_much_data 
    QUALIFY file_row_number <> min(file_row_number) over(partition by filename, id, start1, end1)
) as td 
WHERE d.filename = td.filename and td.id = d.id and td.start1 = d.start1 and td.end1 = d.end1 and td.file_row_number = d.file_row_number;
```

| number of rows deleted |
| --- |
| 2 |

```
SELECT * FROM too_much_data;
```

| FILENAME | ID | START1 | END1 | FILE_ROW_NUMBER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| name_2022/01/01.csv | 262627 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-02 | 1 |
| name_2022/01/02.csv | 262627 | 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-03 | 3 |

Answer (score 1):

If all the fields are duplicated, easiest way would be to replace your table with its deduped self

```
create or replace table your_table as 
select distinct * 
from your_table;
```

Comment: I've just tried this and I still see the same duplicate rows

Comment: @KristiLuna were you working with a temporary table?

Comment: no my table isn't a temp table

Comment: @KristiLuna Does the select portion of this query get you the distinct records?

Comment: it returns all the records in my table (all 18,022) and doesn't filter any rows out, oh I'm sorry! I was looking in our other warehouse, and there is another column there that is the file row number, which is different for each row!

Comment: @KristiLuna If you have 18,022 records, that means 9,011 would be the last file row number of the first batch of upload. Could you not delete rows where file number is greater than 9011? (Assuming file numbers are incremental)

Answer (score 0):

you can use row_number and pickup only where row_number =1 and delete other rows.

```
select * from (
    select column1 as filename,column2 as id, column3 as start1, column4 as end1,
    row_number()   over (partition by filename, id order by filename, id) as rnum
    from values
    (('name_2022/01/01.csv')    ,('262627'), ('2022-01-01'),('2022-01-02')),
    (('name_2022/01/01.csv')    ,('262627'), ('2022-01-01'),('2022-01-02')),
    (('name_2022/01/02.csv')    ,('262627'), ('2022-01-02'),('2022-01-03')),
    (('name_2022/01/02.csv')    ,('262627'), ('2022-01-02'),('2022-01-03'))
)  where rnum = 1
  ;
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, in my question I wanted to know how would I do this without hardcoding the id or date values, is that possible.

Comment: @KristiLuna "the hard coding " is not the SQL you would use, it's there to get "fake data" to show you how you ise the `ROW_NUMBER()` part of the SQL to help.

Answer (score 0):

please find the example where in creating a intermediate table to store the distinct rows.

```
create or replace table tab1 as (select *
from values
    (('name_2022/01/01.csv')    ,('262627'), ('2022-01-01'),('2022-01-02')),
    (('name_2022/01/01.csv')    ,('262627'), ('2022-01-01'),('2022-01-02')),
    (('name_2022/01/02.csv')    ,('262627'), ('2022-01-02'),('2022-01-03')),
    (('name_2022/01/02.csv')    ,('262627'), ('2022-01-02'),('2022-01-03'))
);                                 


-- create intermediate table using analytical functions to remove duplicate rows.
create table uniq_tab1 as  (
select column1 as filename,column2 as id, column3 as start1, column4 as end1
from tab1 
qualify row_number()   over (partition by filename, id order by filename, id) = 1
  );
  
  select * from uniq_tab1;
```